# Cross_val_predict return each test result independently

Tags: scikit-learn

From my understanding cross_val_predict with cv parameter set to 10, will create 10 independent data sets, use one as a test set and the other 9 as training sets, and do this until all 10 sets have been used as the test data. the return is one combined data set containing all the predictions for the data with confidence levels.

What I want is something like an array containing ten arrays of predictions so I can calculate a mean score, i know cross_val_score returns this but I'm trying to compare the ROC AUC metric, so need to use the 'predict_proba' method, below is the code to create the current output I am receiving.

**Here is the output :**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
y_bin = label_binarize(y, classes=['label1','label2'])
#import module to calculate roc_auc score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
#Import the cross-validation prediction module
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
#using the loops to change parameters again
NNmodel = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(10,),activation='logistic')
proba = cross_val_predict(NNmodel, X, y, cv=10, method='predict_proba')
auc = roc_auc_score(y_bin,proba[:,1])
print ("Hidden Neurons set to 10", "ROC AUC Score = %",auc*100)
```

I would much rather report the mean score of each test set rather than just the single result I can produce at the moment.

Comment: If you are just interesting in getting the `roc_auc` metric for each CV fold then I think you can just use `scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=10, scoring='roc_auc')`.

Comment: I was under the assumption that this result can be quite skewed as it does not use the probability's associated with the prediction producing the roc auc based on only one threshold and not the thresholds obtained by using the confidence metric predict_proba provides.